# how to change the default directory for the downloaded file using chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to use below but still the pdf file goes to the old default directory.

```java
String downloadFilepath = "/target";    
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);        
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main problem with your code is that you haven't provided the proper download path.**

```
String downloadFilepath = "/target";
```

**Replace or Change it with below code:**

`String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "target";`

**Complete Code for testing:**

```
String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "target";   
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);    
chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade",true);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
//Example Site for REF
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/download/some-file.txt");
```